# Querying a string consisting exactly a part of a query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field named "lang" which consists values "en_US","en_GB","ru_RU", e.t.c. with this mapping

```
"lang": {
    "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
            "fields": {
               "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
               }
            }
```

How to filter for documents, e.g. from "US"?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is change `"index": "not_analyzed"` on the upper-level field, and set up a [pattern analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) for that field. Since you already have the `"lang.raw"` field set up, you'll still be able to get the untouched version for faceting or whatever.

So, to test it I set up an index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "whitespace_underscore": {
               "type": "pattern",
               "pattern": "[\\s_]+",
               "lowercase": false
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "lang": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "whitespace_underscore", 
               "search_analyzer": "standard", 
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed",
                     "ignore_above": 256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And added a few docs:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"doc1","lang":"en_US"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"doc2","lang":"en_GB"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"doc3","lang":"ru_RU"}
```

Now I can filter by `"US"` like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "lang": "US"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "doc1",
               "lang": "en_US"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And I can still get a list of values with a terms aggregation on `"lang.raw"`:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "lang_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "lang.raw"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "lang_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "en_GB",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "en_US",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "ru_RU",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/ac3f3fd66ea649c0c3a8010241d1f6981a7e012c